# C# LINQ Flatten list of nested objects

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm selecting same object from five different tables in database via EF core. I wanna do it in one database call. So I have IQueryable of anonymous object containing five objects of same type. How do I flatten in to IQueryable<RightsEntity> before calling ToListAsync() ?

```
var q = from people in _dataContext.People.DefaultIfEmpty()
                from groups in _dataContext.Groups.DefaultIfEmpty()
                from contracts in _dataContext.Contracts.DefaultIfEmpty()
                from activities in _dataContext.ActivityTypes.DefaultIfEmpty()
                from vehicles in _dataContext.Vehicles.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new
                {
                    Person = new RightsEntity
                    {
                        ...
                    },
                    Group = new RightsEntity
                    {
                        ...
                    },
                    Contract = new RightsEntity
                    {
                        ...
                    },
                    Activity = new RightsEntity
                    {
                       ...
                    },
                    Vehicle = new RightsEntity
                    {
                        ...
                    }
```

I can imagine to do it after loading from database. But is there any way to make EF Core do that? I haven't found any answer that would fit to my case. [image]

Comment: I imagine that `SelectMany` is what you're after, but it's hard to say because you haven't really provided all the relevant information.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I hope I provided enough informations. From IQueryable above I need to get all objects to List<RightsEntity>

Comment: Define "same object from five different tables". Your question does not show how the query is constructed, nor does it explain how these tables relate to one another.

Comment: Your current code will produce a massive cartesian product. You really should just execute a series of queries for each entity with a union operator.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to flatten the output of each table into a common type, and then do unions. Since you already have your common type defined as `RightsEntity`, you can just select that from each table:

```
var q = _dataContext.People.Select(r => new RightsEntity() { ... }).Union(
        _dataContext.Groups.Select(r => new RightsEntity() { ... })).Union(
        _dataContext.Contracts.Select(r => new RightsEntity() { ... })).Union(
        _dataContext.ActivityTypes.Select(r => new RightsEntity() { ... })).Union(
        _dataContext.Vehicles.Select(r => new RightsEntity() { ... }));
```

This should run as a single batch on the SQL server, something like this:

```
SELECT t1.SomeField1FromTableT1 AS CommonField1, t1.SomeField2FromTableT1 AS CommonField2 FROM People t1
UNION
SELECT t2.SomeField1FromTableT2 AS CommonField1, t2.SomeField2FromTableT2 AS CommonField2 FROM Groups t2
UNION
...
```